# GMB real-time notification settings in pub/sub "reset" every few days

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

**Non-technical person here ‍♂️**

I'm having an issue where (using the Oauth 2.0 Playground) I authorize an internal user's GMB account and configure real-time notifications to be sent to our GCP topic. Every few days or so, notifications stop getting sent to our topic and when I check the notification settings for that account, they have been subscribed to an unknown GCP topic. I can reconfigure the notifications settings again, but every few days they are reconfigured to the unknown GCP topic.

It's possible some other app is overwritting my changes periodically, but I am having trouble figuring out where they're coming from.

Is there a log I can review to know where the request to change the notification settings is coming from?

When using the OAuth 2.0 Playground to configure settings, do they "expire" at some point? If so, is how do I prevent that from happening?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can start looking into when and who created the unknown GCP topics by checking your Cloud Logging for created topics. You can do this by:

- Open your Google Cloud Console
- Open "Logging"
- There should be a "Query" tab and select it.
- Input `protoPayload.methodName="google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.CreateTopic"` and click "Run Query". You can check this [reference](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/audit-logging#audited_operations) if you'd like to see other logs related to Pub/Sub.
- Click "LAST 1 HOUR" to adjust the time parameters of your log query. (Example: adjust it to a whole month to query all Created topics within a month)
- Click the ">" beside the result and expand the log.
- There are lots of info like the created topic name, what email authenticated this request, etc. In your case you should look out for field `authenticationInfo`  for you to check who invoked the request:

  ```
  authenticationInfo: {
  principalEmail: "email-used-to-create-the-topic@example.com"
  principalSubject: "user:email-used-to-create-the-topic@example.com"
  }
  ```

NOTE: For testing purposes I blacked out my project-id and email for this example. Also the topic I created is `log-this-topic` and the email in the log mine since I was the one that created the topic.
[image]

OAuth have set rules for expiration, you can check it on [Refresh Token expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration).

Comment: Thank you for posting this, @ricco-d. I checked the logs, per your instructions above, but the only GCP topic found is the one I created. 

Is it possible that another app is resetting the GMB notifications to a topic in their app?

Comment: @MarkSorenson I see. I assume you adjusted the time frame of log searching. If this is still the case, you can try reaching out to GMB support and let your set up be checked.